# How to divide the image into 64x64 patches overlapping or non blobs coordinate

Tags: python, python-3.6

My English may not be very good. I hope you can understand my question. I have a piece of code that marks the nuclei. I want to determine the center of these blobs coordinates and then patches them into 64x64 pieces.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Dec 20 04:09:16 2019

@author: dogac
"""

#This program will output DAB and Hematoxylin blob counts

#Hematoxylin (Basic blue)= binds to nuclei
#CD3 (T cells) are DAB


import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
import os
import sys
from math import sqrt
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.color import separate_stains, rgb2grey
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
from skimage.feature import blob_dog

file_path='C:/Users/dogac/Desktop/projebitirme/Training_data'
output_path="C:/Users/dogac/Desktop/nucleipatch"
train_labels = os.listdir(file_path)
patch_size=64
stride=64

def blobAndImage2patches(ihc_rgb):
    rgb_from_hrd = np.array([[0.644, 0.710, 0.285],
                             [0.0326, 0.873, 0.487],
                             [0.270, 0.562, 0.781]])
    hrd_from_rgb = linalg.inv(rgb_from_hrd)

    ihc_hrd = separate_stains(ihc_rgb, hrd_from_rgb)

    '''Hematoxylin'''
    #Rescale signals
    #[:, :, 012 color]
    hema_rescale = rescale_intensity(ihc_hrd[:, :, 0], out_range=(0, 1))
    hema_array = np.dstack((np.zeros_like(hema_rescale), hema_rescale, hema_rescale))


    #Blob detection
    image2dH = rgb2grey(hema_array)


    blobs_DoG_Hema = blob_dog(image2dH, min_sigma=5, max_sigma=10, threshold=.4, overlap=0.3)
    blobs_DoG_Hema[:, 2] = blobs_DoG_Hema[:, 2] * sqrt(2)

    blobs = [blobs_DoG_Hema]

    patchSize=64
    blobs = [blobs_DoG_Hema]
    colors = ['blue']
    titles = ['Difference of Gaussian: Hematoxylin']
    sequence = zip(blobs, colors, titles)
    num_blobsH = len(blobs_DoG_Hema)

    subImages=[]
    for blobs, color, title in sequence:
        for blob in blobs:
            y, x,r= blob
            x=int(x)
            y=int(y)
            x = x-int(64//2)
            y = y-int(64//2)
            if x < 0:
                x = 0
            if y < 0:
                y = 0
            if x + patchSize >2000:
                x = 2000 - patchSize
            if y + patchSize >2000:
                y = 2000 - patchSize
            subImg = image2dH[y:y+64,x:x+64]
            subImages.append(subImg)
    return subImages,num_blobsH



import glob
for training_name in train_labels:
    current_label = training_name
    print(training_name)
    j=0
    for imgPath in sorted(glob.glob( file_path +'/'+training_name + '/*.tif')):
        print(imgPath)
        image=data.imread(imgPath)
        subImages,num_blobsH=blobAndImage2patches(image)
        for i in range(num_blobsH):
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_path +'/'+training_name +'/p_{0}.png'.format(j)),255*subImages[i])
            j+=1
```

I solved the problem of creating patches. but not all patches are 64x64 or 128x128. How can I follow a method?

I tried the code I gave below. But I still get the same results:

```
def image2patch(in_image,sequence,num_blobsH, stride=64, patch_size=64):

    shape=in_image.shape
    if shape[0]<patch_size:
        L=0
    else:
        L=math.ceil((shape[0]-patch_size)/stride)
    if shape[1]<patch_size:
        W=0
    else:
        W=math.ceil((shape[1]-patch_size)/stride)

    subImages=[]
    if len(shape)>2:
        full_image=np.pad(in_image, ((0, patch_size+stride*L-shape[0]), (0, patch_size+stride*W-shape[1]), (0,0)), mode='symmetric')
    else:
        full_image=np.pad(in_image, ((0, patch_size+stride*L-shape[0]), (0, patch_size+stride*W-shape[1])), mode='symmetric')

    print(full_image)
    print("-------------------------------------")
    print(in_image)
    for blobs, color, title in sequence:
        for blob in blobs:
            y, x,r= blob
            x=int(x)
            y=int(y)
            x = x-int(64//2)
            y = y-int(64//2)
            if x < 0:
                x = 0
            if y < 0:
                y = 0
            if x + patch_size >2000:
                x = 2000 - patch_size
            if y + patch_size >2000:
                y = 2000 - patch_size
            subImages.append(full_image[x:x+patch_size, y:y+patch_size])
    return subImages
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split

Comment: You should pad them for a fix size like 64x64 with [numpy.pad()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy-pad)